# gulp sourcemaps error output unclear

Tags: gulp

I'm new to gulp and tried to create a sourcemap for my less files. But however it breaks with a `missing semicolon` error. However I can't seem to find the missing semicolon, when I check for errors with my IDE.

I'm using the gulpfile task:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.less + '/styles.less')
    // .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(plumber()) // Checks for errors
    .pipe(maps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']})) // Adds vendor prefixes
    .pipe(pixrem())  // add fallbacks for rem units
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(cssnano()) // Minifies the result
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});
```

and the error is:

```
less/styles.css.map:1:69: Missed semicolon> 1 | {"version":3,"sources":["mixins.less","base.less","responsive.less"],"names":[],"mappings":"A
..........

max-width: 140px;\n                margin: 0 auto;\n                .caption {\n                    font-size: 12px;\n                    background: #fff;\n                    padding: 0 15px;\n                    padding-bottom: 15px;\n                    color: @color-2;\n                    font-family: arial, sans-serif;\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    }\n    \n    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {\n        padding-left: 15px;\n        padding-right: 15px;\n    }\n    \n    .features-video {\n        padding-top: 170px;\n    }\n    \n    .pricing {\n        padding-top: 170px;\n    }\n    \n    .apps-section {\n        padding-top: 160px;\n    }\n    \n    .story-section {\n        padding-top: 170px;\n    }\n    \n    .contact-section {\n        padding-top: 125px;\n    }\n    \n    .bg-slider-wrapper {\n        position: fixed;\n    }\n    \n    \n}\n\n/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */\n@media (min-width: 1200px) {\n \n};\n\n\n"],"file":"styles.css","sourceRoot":"/source/"}
```

Comment: This question isn't particularly useful without your LESS file. Read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the link my less files are here: https://github.com/yunti/less/tree/master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `maps.write()` too early in your pipeline. This emits a `.map` source map file into the stream that subsequent plugins like `autoprefixer` try to parse as CSS. Since source maps files don't contain valid CSS `autoprefixer` throws an error.

Generally you want to put your `maps.write()` calls directly before any `gulp.dest()` calls so that source maps are emitted as late as possible (this also makes sure all previous transformations are recorded in your source maps).

In your case you have two `gulp.dest()` calls, so after the first one you need to filter out the source maps file using [`gulp-filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter). Otherwise `cssnano` will try to parse the source map file and you'll end up with an error again.

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.less + '/styles.less')
    .pipe(plumber()) // Checks for errors
    .pipe(maps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']}))
    .pipe(pixrem())
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))
    .pipe(filter('**/*.css'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});
```

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: Yup, brilliantly explained, always worth more than just an answer.  Thanks for helping me understand.